# Where can I find 100,000 Anthropus Talismans?

Tags: dragons-of-atlantis

I need 100,000 Anthropus Talismans to build an outpost.  Where do I get these talismans? I've attacked many Anthropus camps of all levels 1 - 10 and still do not have a single one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to get Anthropus Talismans, anthropus must be present and a Great or Elemental dragon must be used in the attack.

You can get them from any level of the camps, but there must be Anthropus troops for you to kill to get the talismans.

[Source](http://dragonsofatlantis.wikia.com/wiki/Anthropus)

Comment: Yup, but it can take some time to get them. It helps if you get a powerful army, so you can farm the bigger camps, which yield more Talismans

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, You need to use a great or Elemental Dragon in your attack in order to get the talismans. This will take a long time to get them, since you only get 1 talisman for every 500 anthropus you kill. There fore I reccomend going for the higher camps, around Lvs 7, 8, 9, which I can use 80k-90k LBM and about 2k Armored transports and I won't lose any of the.

Answer (score 0):

attack Level 10 anthropus camp - 100k LBM + 1k ATs (Met 9 Med 7 WC 9)  but unused GD , if use GD it will lest , the easy way to get talimans faster

Answer (score 0):

I like to use troops from my inventory. I suggest not attacking Anthropus Camp at level 11, because I've crushed 75000 sea sirens on it.

Answer (score -1):

you have to atack anthropus camps lvl 5 and hyer to get talismans the fastest way if you atack low level you will get max 100 at 1 atack lvl 6 gives you 220 i dont know above because im still evolving my army the best way to beat the camps is with archers lots and lots of archers until now i have 20000 and im fighting with lvl 10 camps